# How to take screenshot of entire screen on a Jailbroken iOS Device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I need to take screenshot of the whole screen including the status bar, I use `CARenderServerRenderDisplay` to achieve this, it works right on iPad, but wrong at iPhone 6 Plus. As the * marked part in the code, if I set `width=screenSize.width*scale` and `height=screenSize.height*scale`, it will cause crash, if I just change them as:`width=screenSize.height*scale` and `height=screenSize.width*scale`, it will works, but produce a image like that:
[image], I've tried much but no reason found, does anyone know that? I hope I've described it clear enough.

```
- (void)snapshot
{
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

    //*********** the place where problem appears        
    size_t width = screenSize.height * scale;
    size_t height = screenSize.width * scale;
    //***********

    size_t bytesPerElement = 4;
    OSType pixelFormat = 'ARGB';
    size_t bytesPerRow = bytesPerElement * width;
    size_t surfaceAllocSize = bytesPerRow * height;

    NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kIOSurfaceIsGlobal,
                                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:bytesPerElement], kIOSurfaceBytesPerElement,
                                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:bytesPerRow], kIOSurfaceBytesPerRow,
                                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:width], kIOSurfaceWidth,
                                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:height], kIOSurfaceHeight,
                                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:pixelFormat], kIOSurfacePixelFormat,
                                [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:surfaceAllocSize], kIOSurfaceAllocSize,
                                nil];

    IOSurfaceRef destSurf = IOSurfaceCreate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(properties));

    IOSurfaceLock(destSurf, 0, NULL);
    CARenderServerRenderDisplay(0, CFSTR("LCD"), destSurf, 0, 0);
    IOSurfaceUnlock(destSurf, 0, NULL);

    CGDataProviderRef provider =  CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, IOSurfaceGetBaseAddress(destSurf), (width * height * 4), NULL);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8,
                                       8*4, IOSurfaceGetBytesPerRow(destSurf),
                                       CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst |kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little,
                                       provider, NULL, YES, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: My environment is jailbroken iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 9.0.2.

Comment: Your provider can only provide `width * height * 4` bytes, but `CGImageCreate` will ask it for `IOSurfaceGetBytesPerRow(destSurf) * height * 4` bytes. Perhaps that's why it crashes?

Comment: @robmayoff, I took a test just now, it crashed at `CARenderServerRenderDisplay `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Jailbroken environment, you can use the private `UIImage` method [`_UICreateScreenUIImage`](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIImage#UICreateScreenUIImage):

```
OBJC_EXTERN UIImage *_UICreateScreenUIImage(void);

// ...

- (void)takeScreenshot {
    UIImage *screenImage = _UICreateScreenUIImage();
    // do something with your screenshot
}
```

This method uses `CARenderServerRenderDisplay` for faster rendering of the entire device screen.  It replaces the `UICreateScreenImage` and `UIGetScreenImage` methods that were removed in the arm64 version of the iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: do you know how to declare/ call this method in Xamarin ( C# ) ?

Comment: @Benj Hey, I'm not sure how this would work in Xamarin.  Is there a way to load or run a C function?  That's really all this is.

Comment: @JAL thx, I made it work here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099954/ios-screenshot-as-system-drawing-bitmap-xamarin-from-background-app just struggeled for a while in which library to look for the method